# Constant-Width Curves and Circles

Tags: geometry, circles

I recently learnt that a constant-width curve is a curve with continuous constant width, therefore, I believe a circle is a constant-width curve.

However, I am sure there is a property that a circle has and a constant-width curve doesn't.

Thus, my question is:

**What is a property true for circles but false for constant-width curve?**

Also, I'd like to know:

**How do I prove that a constant-width curve has constant-width curve?**

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: See the difference between constant _width_ and constant _radius._ (Which one is necessary for good wheels?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What is a property true for circles but false for constant-width curve?**

There are many such properties. The most obvious ones that I can think of are

1. A circle has a point (its midpoint) which has the same distance (the radius) to every point on the curve.
2. A circle has constant and non-zero curvature.

> **How do I prove that a constant-width curve has constant-width curve?**

Do you mean to ask about how to prove that a curve has [constant width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width)? You'll have to consider all pairs of parallel lines which touch the curve without cutting into its interior. If the curve is convex, then these lines are tangents, so you'd be interested in the pair of tangents for every angle. Perhaps you can use that angle as a parameter. But it really depends on how you describe the curve in the first place.